# IObjectRenderer loaded but not working

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have setup a `IObjectRenderer` for a object but its not using the renderer when logging

Using Log4Net debugging I can see the renderer has loaded and found the correct object type to render but it seems to ignore it.

Output:

```
log4net: Rendering class [ThirdPartyApi.Code.Logging.ModelStateRenderer, ThirdPartyApi], Rendered class [System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary].
log4net: Loaded type [System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary] from assembly [System.Web.Http, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35] by searching loaded assemblies.
```

Log Output:

```
28927 [10]() DEBUG ThirdPartyApi.Controllers.AuthenticationController (null) Debug - Model Validation: System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary
```

Renderer class:

```
public class ModelStateRenderer : IObjectRenderer
{
    public void RenderObject(RendererMap rendererMap, object obj, TextWriter writer)
    {
        var modelStateDict = obj as ModelStateDictionary;
        if (modelStateDict != null)
        {
            foreach (var modelState in modelStateDict)
            {
                writer.Write("Model: {0}, Value: {1}\n", modelState.Key, modelState.Value);
                if (modelState.Value.Errors != null && modelState.Value.Errors.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var error in modelState.Value.Errors)
                    {
                        writer.Write("Error Mssage: {0}\n Exception: {1}\n", error.ErrorMessage, error.Exception);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I breakpoint the above method it never gets hit, so it seems it does not use the renderer at all

Config:

```
  <renderer renderingClass="ThirdPartyApi.Code.Logging.ModelStateRenderer, ThirdPartyApi" renderedClass="System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary" />
```

Anyone have any ideas?

---

EDIT: I have not been able to find an pdb's for Log4net online, and every version I compile does not match the version we have even though the version numbers match.

Might have to add logging to log4net to find why log4net is not logging what it should be logging :)

Answer (score 3):

The log4net RendererMap.FindAndRender() method is the one that figures out which renderer needs to be used.  It looks like this;

```
   public void FindAndRender(object obj, TextWriter writer)
   {
           if (obj == null)
           {
                   writer.Write(SystemInfo.NullText);          // <=== here!!!
           }
           else
           {
                   // etc..
           }
   }
```

This explains why you see `(null)` in the logging output.  Or in other words, the object you are trying to log is *null*.  So of course your renderer isn't called.

Comment: The object is not null, I just redacted some of the line, The ModelStateDictonary gets rendered as ToString() `System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary` instead of using the renderer, but I will look into the `FindAndRender` method and see whats going on so thanks for that clue

Comment: Hmm, that's some very unhelpful redacting.  Well, you now know which method to set the breakpoint on.

Comment: The log line example was showing what was logged instead of the renderer, but the weird thing is no renderers are working in the entire application, they all seem to load ok, but are never used.

Comment: have not had any luck debugging log4net, cannot find any symbols and VS is looking for log4netLogger.cs which des not exist in the source :( I think Ninject is messing up the rendering stuff, might be time to derive `ModelStateDictionary` and override `ToString()` thanks for the help though.